# Table doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

We have ran a Dump using MySQL Workbench, using mysqldump version 8.0.20, on an RDS Instance running MySQL 5.7.38.

Following the dump, we cannot access 1 table, specifically the error we are getting is:

`Error Code: 1146. Table 'db_name.table1' doesn't exist   0.215 sec`

The dump logs say the following:

```
Running: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump --defaults-file="/var/folders/m7/h9sw24cx7698gpn46zpm7cp80000gp/T/tmpE8YzFp/extraparams.cnf"  --user=user --host=db_host --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --column-statistics=0 --skip-triggers "db_name"
Warning: A partial dump from a server that has GTIDs will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that changed suppressed parts of the database. If you don't want to restore GTIDs, pass --set-gtid-purged=OFF. To make a complete dump, pass --all-databases --triggers --routines --events.
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'db_name.table1' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

We cannot figure out what we've done wrong, and given we're not sure we can SSH into the RDS instance to backup the MySQL file, we are completely in the dark as to what the solution might be.

Comment: _Following the dump, we cannot access 1 table,_ Do you mean you cannot see that table on the restored database? Or on the original database

Comment: We cannot see contents of table1 in the original database any longer, we have not imported the dump anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the user has permission/access to the tables. Run the following if the table exists and is accessible:

```
1SQL> show tables like 'table1';
2SQL> select * from table1;
```

Validate if the data file (*.frm, *.ibd) for table1 is available as well by checking the data-dir MySQL. I suspect the table1 is corrupt, incase of that you should repair or restore the table from backup.